# How to update json in postgres array?

Tags: postgresql, jsonb, postgresql-9.5

I have attached the JSON  Input and Output

Input

```
{
  "cap1": [
    {
      "fe1": [
        {
          "par1": 0,
          "fet1": 6,
          "fun1": [
            {
              "fnd1": [
                {
                  "name": "v1",
                  "site": [
                    "w1",
                    "mb1",
                    "tb1"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "capab1": 2
    },
    {
      "fe1": [
        {
          "par1": 0,
          "fet1": 42,
          "fun1": null
        },
        {
          "par1": 42,
          "fet1": 43,
          "fun1": null
        }
      ],
      "capab1": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to add `{"par1": 0, "fet1": 44, "fun1": null},{"par1": 0, "fet1": 45, "fun1": null}` where `"capab1": 11`.

Output should be

```
{
  "cap1": [
    {
      "fe1": [
        {
          "par1": 0,
          "fet1": 6,
          "fun1": [
            {
              "fnd1": [
                {
                  "name": "v1",
                  "site": [
                    "w1",
                    "mb1",
                    "tb1"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ],
      "capab1": 2
    },
    {
      "fe1": [
        {
          "par1": 0,
          "fet1": 42,
          "fun1": null
        },
        {
          "par1": 42,
          "fet1": 43,
          "fun1": null
        },
        {
          "par1": 0,
          "fet1": 44,
          "fun1": null
        },
        {
          "par1": 0,
          "fet1": 45,
          "fun1": null
        }
      ],
      "capab1": 11
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Question aside, it is bad practice to store deeply nested JSON in SQL, especially when it needs to be updated frequently. 

I'd rather fetch and manipulate the JSON in program, then update the DB record. But still, it performs poorly.

Comment: this is master data. we need to update once in a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a bit complex. you can use `jsonb_array_elements` to unnest the array and get the path to be updated. Then update the JSON using `JSONB_INSERT` like below:
Here is the solution:

```
with cte as (
select  *,
('{cap1,'||index1-1||',fe1,0}')::text[] as json_path
from test,
jsonb_array_elements(col->'cap1') with ordinality arr1 (vals1,index1)
where (vals1->>'capab1')::int=11
)
 update test 
 set col = jsonb_insert(test.col,cte.json_path,'[{"par1": 0, "fet1": 44, "fun1": null},{"par1": 0, "fet1": 45, "fun1": null}]'::jsonb,true) 
 from cte 
 where test.id=cte.id
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=57f10a3a2388fec257d560a8f4053734)